# Prevent Kestrel From Crashing When Port Is In Use

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I suspect this is an 'odd' thing that I'm trying to do but...I have configured Kestrel to listen on several ports.  The thing is, sometimes, one of those ports is already in use.

This is currently causing my application to crash.

The behavior I'd like to see, is that it listens on all of the available ports that I have specified.  But I haven't been able to find any examples/documentation on the topic.

As example, I might configure it to listen on 90, 91, 92, 93...but if port 91 is already in use, I want it to only listen on ports 90, 92, 93.  I don't mind if it throws an exception or logs an error, so long as I can get it to continue.  I'd like to avoid 'checking first' and then altering the configuration since that feels like a race condition waiting to happen)

Can anyone tell me how to allow Kestrel to start on only the available ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **port 0**; with that, Kestrel dynamically binds to an available port at runtime as said [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#port-0):

```
private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://*:0");
```

Also, you can determine which port Kestrel actually bound at runtime like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWebHost webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    webHost.Start();

    string address = webHost.ServerFeatures
        .Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()
        .Addresses
        .First();

    int port = int.Parse(address.Split(':')[4]);
}
```

**Update:**

You can check ports availability and start the project if specified ports are not being used by other applications:

```
private static string[] GenerateUrls(IEnumerable<int> ports)
{
    return ports.Select(port => $"http://localhost:{port}").ToArray();
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetAvailablePorts(IEnumerable<int> ports)
{
    IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    IPEndPoint[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpListeners();

    IEnumerable<int> allActivePorts = tcpConnInfoArray.Select(endpoint => endpoint.Port).ToList();

    return ports.Where(port => !allActivePorts.Contains(port)).ToList();
}
```

And the final result will be like this :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    IWebHostBuilder webHost = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    int[] ports = { 5000, 5050, 8585 };

    IEnumerable<int> availablePorts = GetAvailablePorts(ports).ToList();
    if (!availablePorts.Any())
        throw new InvalidOperationException("There are no active ports available to start the project.");

    webHost.UseUrls(GenerateUrls(availablePorts));

    return webHost;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer and using port 0 sounds like it would be helpful in a lot of situations; but I need it to start on multiple, specific ports.  If that makes any sense.  I tried to edit the question and make it more clear.  I'd like to give it a list of ports {20,21,22} and have it listen on whichever of those three are available.