# How To Prevent Port Sharing With Kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, asp.net-core, port

On my Windows machine, I'm struggling to understand the behavior I'm seeing with Kestrel and asp.net core with regards to port conflicts with other processes on the machine. I want to prevent a situation where Kestrel and another process are both listening on the same port.

I have an application using Kestrel and I want it to either be listening or to detect a conflict and log an error message.

I also have a small console app that is using Sockets to listen (`new Socket(ipPoints[i].AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)`) on the same ports as my Kestrel app (80 and 443).

Starting with just the console app running the output of `netstat -Aof | grep LISTEN | grep ':80\s\|:443\s'` displays:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172
  TCP    [::]:80                mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172  
  TCP    [::]:443               mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172
```

I can open a web browser and see the connection establish with the console app.

While this program is still running, I launch my asp.net core website. I was expecting an error of some sort, but instead it appears to work fine. Repeating the netstat command, I see both processes are now listening in the exact same way.

`netstat -Aof | grep LISTEN | grep ':80\s\|:443\s'` displays:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172
  TCP    [::]:80                mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172  
  TCP    [::]:443               mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       53172                             
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       19728
  TCP    [::]:80                mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       19728
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       19728  
  TCP    [::]:443               mymachine.mydomain.com:0  LISTENING       19728
```

Oddly enough, if I run my Kestrel application twice, the second one will fail with the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address https://[::]:443: address already in use.

Which is the behavior I was hoping to see. But when it's not a second instance of kestrel, and it's just something else using the ports, I seem to be able to have kestrel running and listening, but not receiving the traffic.

I'm only distributing the Kestrel application. We've had a report from a user that says 'Well the application is running, there are no errors in the log file, and the status tool you provide says everything is okay, but when I go to http://example.com nothing loads'

Other software was interfering. I know we can't control a user's environment and there will always be potential for a misconfigured something or other to prevent my application from running as expected, but I'd like to give the user the best experience possible.

Is there a way to prevent this type of port sharing from within my Kestrel application or for Kestrel to throw an error when it happens? If not, is there a best-practice approach to detecting these conflicts?

**Sample Console App**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace PortListener
{
    // Borrowed from SO Mohsan Saleem's answer (which was borrowed from MSDN answer
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/52361311/73381
    // Slightly updated
    class ListenPorts
    {
        private readonly Socket[] _socketConnections;
        private readonly IPEndPoint[] _ipPoints;
    
        internal ListenPorts(IPEndPoint[] ipPoints)
        {
            _ipPoints = ipPoints;
            _socketConnections = new Socket[ipPoints.Length];
        }
    
        public void BeginListening()
        {
            for (var i=0;i<_ipPoints.Length;i++)
            {
                _socketConnections[i] = new Socket(_ipPoints[i].AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _socketConnections[i].Bind(_ipPoints[i]);
                var thread = new Thread(ListenerThread);
                thread.Start(_socketConnections[i]);
            }
        }
        
        private static void ListenerThread(object? objs)
        {
            var socket = objs as Socket;
            var data = new byte[1024];
    
            IPEndPoint sender;
                
            sender = socket.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork ? 
                new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0) : 
                new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 0);
    
            EndPoint Remote = sender;
    
            try
            {
                socket.Listen(100);
                var newSocket = socket.Accept();
                newSocket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref Remote);
                newSocket.Close();
                
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
    
            Console.WriteLine(socket.LocalEndPoint + " -->  {0}: ", Remote.ToString());
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {

            IPEndPoint[] ipPoints = {
                new (IPAddress.IPv6Any, 443),
                new (IPAddress.IPv6Any, 80),
                new (IPAddress.Any, 443),
                new (IPAddress.Any, 80),
            };
            var portListener = new ListenPorts(ipPoints);
            portListener.BeginListening();
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Now listening on \n{string.Join("\n", ipPoints.Select(x=>x.Address + " " + x.Port))}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Kestrel Application**
This is a little harder to share but this is likely the relevent bits from a sample app that exhibits the same behavior

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("https://mymachine.mydomain.com:443;http://mymachine.mydomain.com:80");
            });
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share you console app?

Comment: Check out this link for a possible way to circumvent Kestrel port conflicts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607479/prevent-kestrel-from-crashing-when-port-is-in-use

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your console app, not in Kestrel. Your app does not listen in exclusive mode so Kestrel is able to listen on the port too. Set [`Socket.ExclusiveAddressUse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.exclusiveaddressuse?view=net-8.0) to `true` (tested on Windows, do not have setup for Unix ATM):

```
public void BeginListening()
{
    for (var i=0;i<_ipPoints.Length;i++)
    {
        _socketConnections[i] = new Socket(_ipPoints[i].AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _socketConnections[i].ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. 

In practice, I only am distributing the Kestrel application. This came from a user who reported no errors but also that our application was not responding. I'm fairly ignorant when it comes to networking and perhaps this is expected behavior but I was hoping provide more clear direction to the users that something else is causing a conflict.

Comment: @RobP. was glad to help! As for why the app is not responding - there could be a myriad of reasons (and yes it always a headache to figure out what is going wrong on the customer side).